# polymer web component #shadow root not displaying

Tags: polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I am trying to run a simple polymer web component on a localhost server on my mac.

I think I have followed the tutorial correctly but the #shadow root information is not appearing within the  element tag (as you can see in the image) .

The imports are working because polymer.html is being imported in. I can't figure out why the information is not being displayed with the element I have set up. When I run it in safari the H1 appears briefly (for less than a second) then disappears so this tells me polymer is set up properly it just isn't being pulled into the #shadow root of  for some reason...

I have been fighting with this for a couple of days.

any help you can give would ber great and save me many more headaches :)

Cheers guys!!

```html
THIS IS THE OUTPUT ON THE LOCAL HOST SERVER...


<html><head><style>body {transition: opacity ease-in 0.2s; } 
body[unresolved] {opacity: 0; display: block; overflow: hidden; position: relative; } 
</style>
    <!-- 1. Load platform support before any code that touches the DOM. -->
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Load the component using an HTML Import -->
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

  </head>
  <body>
   
   <polymer-element name="bens-element" noscript="">
       
       <template>
           
           <h1>This is the shadow dom</h1>
       </template>
   </polymer-element>
    <!-- 3. Declare the element by its tag. -->
    <bens-element></bens-element>
  
</body></html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- 1. Load platform support before any code that touches the DOM. -->
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Load the component using an HTML Import -->
    <link rel="import"href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

  </head>
  <body>
   
   <polymer-element name="bens-element" noscript>
       
       <template>
           
           <h1>This is the shadow dom</h1>
       </template>
   </polymer-element>
    <!-- 3. Declare the element by its tag. -->
    <bens-element></bens-element>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>Safari has no native support for shadow dom yet. It is able to run your polymer application using polyfills. The web component standard is not yet supported on most browsers.
Run the application on **Google Chrome**. You'll see the `#shadow root`.</s>

Check this page for information for [browser compatibility](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/resources/compatibility.html)

`unresolved` attribute is used to mark that the page is not yet initialised.

Edit:

These are causing you problem -

> > **You're using tagged version of dependencies**

I tried building using the versions of dependencies that you're using. Same result. I checked and are just tagged releases. Polymer is still in beta and undergoing heavy development. The latest release from the repo that you should be using are - polymer 0.9.0 and webcomponentsjs 0.6.1

It is the polymer dependency that's causing the behaviour in your case. Because I use webcomponentsjs 0.7.0 for all development. Use bower to resolve your dependencies. Will be simpler if you remove the bower_components folder an bower.json and reinstall the dependencies

> > **The body tag should contain the unresolved attribute.**

This is done to prevent unresolved data-bindings and rules from being displayed in the browser. Because custom elements of polymer take time to initialise. Otherwise you’ll see a lot of double moustache symbols - {{}} in page for data bindings and also missing style rules or an empty page.

WebComponents.js adds a style rule for selector `body[unresolved]` to the page when it is initialised. It sets the opacity to 0 - invisible. So no contents are displayed yet.

After Polymer has successfully initialised all custom-elements, the templates and data bindings resolved, it removes the `unresolved` attribute.
The page fades into view over 200ms because of another `body` style rule added on webcoponents initialisation.

Check the head tag for these two style rules added when the page has initialised.

Comment: hi new-kid, Thanks for the reply - I have run the app in chrome and I get the same result.Nothing shows.  I only ran it in safari out of curiosity :S

Comment: I don't think that polymer.html is getting imported. I checked that the style rules inserted in the `<head>` tag are also inserted by `webcomponents.js`

Check again for polymer import!
Which version of polymer and webcomponents.js are you using? Check for it in bower.json

Comment: And you've missed the `unresolved` attribute in the body tag.

Comment: Thanks new-kid. Can you explain a bit more about the unresolved attribute? Thanks

Comment: Thanks...I will give the unresolved attribute a go. With regard to the polymer.html being imported. I think that it is because when the page has loaded I am able to expand the elements of the imported code and view polymer.html.

Comment: I thought it worked for you. If it does, mark the answer as correct. :)

Comment: Hi... I added <body unresolved> and unfortunately there was still no output to the element tag.... :S

Comment: Check and tell me the version of webcomponents.js and polymer that you're using. They're in bower.json

Comment: "name": "polymer",
  "version": "0.9.1",

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "webcomponentsjs": "^0.7.1"
  },

Comment: Check if webcomponents.min.js is includeed or not.
See it in the Safari Resources section of developer tools.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Check it. That will fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks new-kid. Once I have removed the bower_components folder how I do I reinstall the correct versions of polymer and webcomponentsjs dependencies? Thanks

Comment: Use bower.

`bower init`
`bower install --save polymer/polymer`

That should install all the dependencies correctly.
Check the Getting Started page on polymer-project.org

Comment: Thanks - I will give that a go but I am sure that is what I did last time and it downloaded the latest version of polymer. I will let you know.

Comment: Nope...I deleted the bower_components file and reinstalled and still no luck. If you could point me in the direction of a reliable tutorial/instructions I will delete everything and start a new project...this is sooooo frustrating :) thanks for your help

Comment: Follow the getting started guide on the website of polymer -
Installation - https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/start/getting-the-code.html

Tutorial - https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/start/creatingelements.html